# ns-3 802.11e EDCA TXOP, Specific Mac Layer

Tags: ns-3

I'm ns-3 newbie and I want to simulate with 802.11e EDCA mac layer for TXOP.
I can find some simple example about point to point,
with `PointToPointHelper` And `UdpEcho(Client/Server)Helper` classes.
I could also get a fact that there are `CsmaHelper` class and wifi/model/edca_txop.cc file.

But I couldn't find how to simulate with 802.11e mac layer.
I would not know which application class is used, or which helper class is used, exactly.

So If you guys have some knowledge, may I ask you to tell me?
If it is difficult, could you give some simple example please? then I will try to understand how to use, which class can be used.

If this ask is rude, then give me some link for how to use 802.11e edca please. And also teach me rule of this site and netiquette also please, if It is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the NS-3 [Documentation](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/models/html/wifi-design.html)

For IEEE 802.11e

> QoS-based EDCA and queueing extensions of 802.11e
> an attribute QosSupported that allows configuration of 802.11e/WMM-style QoS support
> The `ns3::DcaTxop` object is used high MACs that are not QoS-enabled, and for transmission of frames (e.g., of type Management) that the standard says should access the medium using the DCF. `ns3::EdcaTxopN` is is used by QoS-enabled high MACs and also performs 802.11n-style MSDU aggregation.

For scope and limitations.

> At the MAC layer, most of the main functions found in deployed Wi-Fi
> equipment for 802.11a/b/e/g are implemented, but there are scattered
> instances where some limitations in the models exist. Most notably,
> 802.11n/ac configurations are not supported by adaptive rate controls; only the so-called ConstantRateWifiManager can be used by those
> standards at this time. Support for 802.11n and ac is evolving. Some
> additional details are as follows:
>
> - 802.11g does not support 9 microseconds slot
> - **802.11e TXOP is not supported**
> - BSSBasicRateSet for 802.11b has been assumed to be 1-2 Mbit/s
> - BSSBasicRateSet for 802.11a/g has been assumed to be 6-12-24 Mbit/s
> - cases where RTS/CTS and ACK are transmitted using HT formats are not supported

Comment: thanks for reply and sorry for my late response. I'll try to simulate my custom ns3 for 802.11e TXOP. thanks!